# How to tell if IntersectionObserver is still observing something

Tags: javascript, dom, viewport

I'm using IntersectionObserver to watch a group of items, and then unobserving each one after it is altered by my callback.

```
var watchItems = new IntersectionObserver(alterItem,{threshold:[0.3]}),
items = $(".item");

for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    watchItems.observe(items[i]);
}

function alterItem(observation) {
    observation.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item.isIntersecting) {
            // do stuff
            watchItems.unobserve(item.target);
        }
    });
}
```

If all my items go through this process, I'd like to completely deactivate the observer using eg `watchItems.disconnect()`. I'm not sure what sort of memory impact it might have by leaving it open, maybe negligible, but I like to close things when I'm done with them as good practice.

I know I can figure it out by tracking the number of items and matching it to how many times one was unobserved, or by using a data attribute, whatever, but what I'm wondering is if anybody knows whether it's inherent in the API. It's obviously keeping track of existing observers somehow, I'd like to know where & if I can access that.

Looking at the IntersectionObserver object before and after using it to place observers gives no real clues that I can find.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @aphextwix Nope, my conclusion for the time being is that there is no access to that information.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called [takeRecords()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/takeRecords) but it returns an element (which was observed), even if there are no more elements to be observed.

I solved it by simply adding a counter to the un- / observed elements, here a example (Angular and Typescript used):

```js
[...]

private observedElements: number = 0;

[...]

// Adding elements to be observed

this.observer.observe(myItem.nativeElement);
this.observedElements++;

[...]

// If element is visible

if (observerEntry.isIntersecting) {

   this.observer.unobserve(observerEntry.target);
   this.observedElements--;

   if (this.observedElements === 0) {

      this.observer.disconnect();
      this.observer = null;

   }

}

[...]
```

Adapt it to your needs and save memory :).

Hope it helps.

Cheers
Unkn0wn0x